# how to plot error bars on top of previous data using pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot a set of points with error bars on top of a very dense scatter plot, and the error bars are hidden behind the data as shown in the attached figure.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}
    \addplot[blue,mark=x] table [x index=0,y index=1]
      {PSF_blue_0_prof.dat};
    \addplot[green,mark=x, error bars/.cd,y explicit,y dir=both]
      table [x index=0,y index=1,y error index=2]
      {PSF_blue_1.0_prof.dat};
  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Data files are available here:

- https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3Hv-zV2q5IcR3l2YTRHTm9qdkE/edit
- https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3Hv-zV2q5IcbzZmSVU5bHhjOFk/edit

The green data points are added in the end using `error bars/.cd,y explicit,y dir=both` but the error bars appear behind the previous blue and red data. How could I plot the error bars in this figure?

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: @percusse I have updated the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Possibility 1: `clip mode=individual`

You need to set `clip mode=individual`. The `clip mode`controls whether markers are placed on top of everything else (`clip mode=global`) or are overdrawn by following plots (`clip mode=individual`). But **some parts** of the plot can overflow the axis boundaries which may be undesirable.
From the `pgfplots` manual:

> The choice `global` tells pgfplots to install one single clip path for
>   the complete picture. In order to avoid clipped marker paths, any
>   markers are processed after the clip path has been closed, i.e. on a
>   separate layer (see `clip marker paths`). An unexpected side effect is
>   that marks are on top of plots, even if the plots have been added
>   after the markers. The choice `individual` instructs pgfplots to install
>   a separate clip path for every `\addplot` command. Consequently, the
>   plot will be clipped. But most importantly, its markers will be drawn
>   immediately after the clip path has been deactivated.

[image]

### Possibility 2: `clip marker paths=true`

Another option is to set `clip marker paths=true` instead. Then the plot will be clipped by the axis' boundaries. This option prevents an overflow of the plot over the axis' boundaries.

> The initial choice `clip marker paths=false` causes markers to be
>   drawn after the clipped region. Only their positions will be clipped.
>   As a consequence, markers will be drawn completely, or not at all. The
>   value `clip marker paths=true` is here for backwards compatibility: it
>   does not introduce special marker treatment, so markers may be drawn
>   partially if they are close to the clipping boundary. This key has no
>   effect if `clip=false`. Note that `clip marker paths` also acts the
>   sequence in which plots and their markers are drawn on top of each
>   other.

[image]

### Possibility 3: `clip=false`

Finally there is also the possibility to set `clip=false`. Then the **entire** plot won't be clipped by the axis' boundaries. This feature can be useful if you use only one x and one y axis.

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}[
    % clip mode=individual,      % Possibility 1
    % clip marker paths=true,    % Possibility 2
    % clip=false,                % Possibility 3 
    ymin=1e-5
    ]
    \addplot[blue, mark=x] table [x index=0,y index=1]
      {PSF_blue_0_prof.dat};
    \addplot[green,mark=x, error bars/.cd,y explicit,y dir=both]
      table [x index=0,y index=1,y error index=2]
      {PSF_blue_1.0_prof.dat};
  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have used `clip marker paths` because I want to clip the lower part of the plot.

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro I've found a third possibility if you want your plot to overflow: `clip=false`. I've updated my answer a final time to show this too.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! it is good to know about the clip options.